# Possible values of $z$ in this inequality problem?

Tags: algebra-precalculus, inequality, fractions

If $0<x<y<z$ integers

And $\frac{1}{x}+\frac{1}{y}+\frac{1}{z}=\frac{1}{4}$

So it asks the possible values of $z$.

Options goes as:

A)9 
B)10 
C)11 
D)12 
E)13

Comment: I have added that $x,y,z$ are integers. Next time, show that you have worked a little on the questions you are working on.

Comment: Since my native language isn't English, I have to translate everything myself. I will be more careful though.

Comment: Welcome to Mathematics Stack Exchange! A quick [tour](https://math.stackexchange.com/tour) will enhance your experience. Here are helpful tips to [write a good question](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/9959/how-to-ask-a-good-question/9960#9960) and [write a good answer](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer). For equations, use [MathJax](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

13 is the answer.

Since $1/x \gt 1/y \gt 1/z$

Hence $1/4 = 1/x+1/y+1/z \gt 1/z +1/z +1/z$

Hence $1/4 \gt 3/z$

Giving $z\gt 12$

Comment: I didn't get the second part. Why did you sum 1/z three times and how do you know that the total is smaller than 1/4?

Comment: edited, $1/4 = 1/x+1/y+1/z \gt 1/z +1/z +1/z$

Comment: Typo on the fourth line: $1/4 > 3/z$.